# Dynamic highchart is not getting displayed Angular js

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

High chart is not getting displayed on UI angular JS MVC c#

Below is my code and I am getting this [9.0,10.99,15.5,19.7,7.0,13.2]data dynamically. I have tried in different ways but it is not working.

I am working on high charts first time.  Can anyone please help me on this

```
      <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>


   <div id="container" style="min-width:310px; height:400px;margin:0 auto"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;
    var Params = [];
    var DSet = [];

    var PprofileId = 1;
    var PparamName = 'Motor RPM';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ThirdPartyDriveData/GetDriveDataByIdAndName',
        data: { profileId: PprofileId, paramName: PparamName },
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            $.each(data.data, function (index, item) {
                debugger;
                if (item.Dataset != '' && item.Dataset >= 0) {
                    DSet.push(item.Dataset);
                    Params.push(item.ParameterName);
                }
            });
            //alert(result);
            CreateChart(DSet, Params);
            //alert(response);
        },
        Error: function () { }

    });
   });

   function CreateChart(DSet) {

    debugger;
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                enableMouseTracking: false
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Parameter',
            data: DSet
        }]
      });
     }
     </script>
```

Can anyone please help me on this

Comment: Could you tell me if you are getting any specific errors? I tested your chart configuration and it seems to be working correctly. Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4mqwL9y8/

Comment: I am not getting any error simply nothing displayed. and no error

Comment: When I pass dynamic object instead of static array, nothing is displayed

Comment: Would you mind reproducing the issue in an online editor so I can investigate what is not working? Since your chart config is correct it is probably something with the data you are trying to pass to the highcharts.

Comment: js fiddler it is working fine but not working in my code. Not sure what the problem is?

Comment: I after reading Highcharts doc I find out the issue. We need to apply parseFloat function on dynamic array. It got resolved my issue.